# How do I add a line without getting into the docker-compose.yml

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker-compose file. I am looking to automate it. I have used the .tpl in terraform for this purpose. I am looking to add add env virables into the docker-compose file from the .tpl file. Can anyone help me with any command to do so?

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update

cd /home/ubuntu/
sudo git clone https://github.com/zendesk/samson.git
cd /home/ubuntu/samson
sudo apt install docker.io -y
sudo apt install docker-compose -y
sudo nano docker-compose.yml
//Here is where the command will go//
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

This is the docker-compose file

```
version: "2"
services:
  samson:
    image: zendesk/samson:latest # replace with `build: .` to use Dock>    ports:
      - "3000:9080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    DATABASE_URL: "sqlite3:///app/db/development.sqlite3"
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 1
    command: ["./script/docker_dev_server"]
```

Comment: What things are you hoping to configure?  You can set Compose [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) to pass through environment variables from the host, or use [`env_file:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) to use a local file created at deployment time, and that potentially gets around the need to edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sed` command to change the content of a specific line for whatever you want to.

This will be tricky if you want more than one environment variable (since it's a `yaml` file and everything needs to be in the right place...), so I would recommend to use a `.env file` if you can. But the idea is the following:

**`docker-compose.yml` file:**

```
version: "2"
services:
  samson:
    image: zendesk/samson:latest # replace with `build: .` to use Dock>    
    ports:
      - "3000:9080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    DATABASE_URL: "sqlite3:///app/db/development.sqlite3"
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 1
    environment:
      REPLACE
    command: ["./script/docker_dev_server"]
```

**`Bash` file:**

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
cd /home/ubuntu/
sudo git clone https://github.com/zendesk/samson.git
cd /home/ubuntu/samson
sudo apt install docker.io -y
sudo apt install docker-compose -y
sudo sed 's~REPLACE~- VAR=test~' docker-compose.yml       # Line that replaces the value
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

One way to do it with a `.env file`, if you can't simply have the file with what you want, is by building it **at runtime** [like: `<content to add> > .env` before the `sed` line (also, to use a `.env file` you would need to **replace** `environment` with `env_file`)]